# What is this apparently non-standard struct packing syntax fed into GCC?

Tags: gcc, struct, syntax, packing

I am a little bit dumbstruck by some code that is associated with a 3rd-party code base I'm working with. All code is written in C or assembler except for a number of files adhering to the syntax described below. I cannot find any documentation on this syntax yet GCC swallows it without any problem. It's GCC 8 I work with. The syntac must be some extension to GCC. It would be very nice if somebody could enlighten me as to exactly what extension it is and where it is documented.

The code obviously defines struct types with packing and uses syntax like this:

- Comment lines begin with "--"
- Keywords are "block", "padding", "field", and "field_high", possibly more. A typical piece of code looks like this:

```
block <BLOCK_NAME> {
    field <FIELD_NAME_NO_1> 1
    field <FIELD_NAME_NO_2> 1
    padding 8
    field_high <FIELD_NAME_NO_3> 6
}
```

A block can contain any number of fields and paddings. The numbers given always add up to a word length on the target architecture.

Files containing this kind of code most often have ".bf" es their extension while ".c" can occur too. Some files have #include's referring to ordinary C headers while some ordinary C files have #includes referring to ".bf" files.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mat :).

Comment: I can't reproduce (get this to compile). Could you provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please? Including the compiler invocation command.

Comment: Ok, good point. I'll try, may take a moment.

Comment: Actually it's an open source code base. It's a micro kernel OS called seL4 - the homepage is located at seL4.systems . A source tree can be obtained by repo init -u https://github.com/seL4/sel4test-manifest.git followed by repo sync. One of those files appears at kernel/libsel4/mode_include/64/sel4/shared_types.bf . I have posted the same question to the seL4 Devel mailing list. Whoever answers first will receive the most gratitude :).

Comment: I poked around for a while and couldn’t figure this out either. Fascinating question.

Comment: @cocoban, looking at the last message in that thread, I see your invocation command, which seems to asnwer the question: gcc is simply used as a C preprocessor there (note the `-E` -- and `-P` switches).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot to everybody who answered.

My conclusion is that GCC preprocessing is used to generate bitfield files on the fly. The basic building blocks in that are pre-existing bitfield files that may refer to other such files via #includes. At certain points, the Python utility is used to translate bitfield files to C code.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the `tools` directory in the Git repository found me [bitfield_gen.py](https://github.com/seL4/seL4/blob/master/tools/bitfield_gen.py), which claims to be a code generator for "bitfield structures". I presume that's what `.bf` stands for.

There are some CMake functions for building bitfield targets in [tools/helpers.cmake](https://github.com/seL4/seL4/blob/master/tools/helpers.cmake#L98). That will probably make sense to people more familiar with CMake than I am.

Answer (score 0):

The Bit Field Generator is documented here http://research.davidcock.fastmail.fm/papers/Cock_08.pdf